# Creating multiple input features in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, clip, multi-values

I am a novice GIS user.

I am trying to clip multiple input features using the ModelBuilder and expecting multiple outputs.

How do I create multiple input (I've seen the several overlapped oval as shown below)?

[image]

Comment: You can use [Iterate feature classes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-feature-classes.htm)

Answer (score 2):

As @Moh points out you can use the `Iterate Feature Classes` tool.
You'll find it in `Insert -> Iterators -> Iterate Feature Class`.
By this you can iterate through multiple input features in a folder or a Feature Dataset.
This means that all feature classes in your folder/feature dataset will be clipped (or whatever operation you wish to perform).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Do you also know how to create overlapped input features as shown in the above figure in ModelBuilder?

Comment: I have troubles understanding what your goal is. I think however, that the way multiple inputs are displayed in the picture you provided is just for representation.